# Why my tensorflow do not perform properly

Tags: python, tensorflow

I tried to work tensorflow on my computer but the error message shows as follows[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNo3h.png), I did install the tensorflow by following the exact instruction of the official website through pip, I do not understand why it happens. Does anyone have the same question as me?

I think the problem is at the exit code, but I do not find any information about this code.

```
x_train shape: (50000, 32, 32, 3)
50000 train samples
10000 test samples
y_train shape: (50000, 1)
2022-01-29 23:19:00.983142: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-01-29 23:19:01.360020: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3493 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
Epoch 1/20
2022-01-29 23:19:03.467200: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:366] Loaded cuDNN version 8302

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)
```

Comment: Which Cuda version are you using? On Linux you can use `nvcc —version` to retrieve it from command line. If you are using a Docker container, run the command inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have installed `CUDA, cuDNN` version compatible to your `tensorflow` version. You can check the [build configurations](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) details here.

Also check [how to install tensorflow using pip](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) and make sure you have followed correct path to install the `tensorflow`.